# How to connect to TimesTen database using golang?

Tags: go, timesten

I am trying to connect TimesTen database using golang, but no TimesTen driver for golang is available I can find.

Does anybody have such experience using golang to access TimesTen?

Since TimesTen supports OCI api. So I am trying to use a go package called goracle at https://github.com/go-goracle/goracle but failed.

Here is my sys.odbc.ini and sys.tt for TimesTen:

> [root@centos-7 ~]# more /var/TimesTen/sys.odbc.ini
>
> [ODBC Data Sources] TT_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2 Driver
>   sampledb_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2 Driver sampledbCS_1122=TimesTen 11.2.2
>   Client Driver
>
> [TT_1122] Driver=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libtten.so
>   DataStore=/var/TimesTen/tt1122/TT_1122 DatabaseCharacterSet=US7ASCII
>
> [sampledb_1122] Driver=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libtten.so
>   DataStore=/var/TimesTen/tt1122/DemoDataStore/sampledb_1122 PermSize=40
>   TempSize=32 PLSQL=1 DatabaseCharacterSet=US7ASCII
>
> [sampledbCS_1122] TTC_SERVER=ttLocalHost_tt1122
>   TTC_SERVER_DSN=sampledb_1122
>   Driver=/opt/TimesTen/tt1122/lib/libttclient.so

--

> [root@centos-7 TimesTen]# more sys.ttconnect.ini
>
> [ttLocalHost_tt1122] Description=TimesTen Server
>   Network_Address=ttLocalHost TCP_PORT=53397

```
db, err := sql.Open("goracle","root/XXXXXXX@localhost:53397/sampledbCS_1122:timesten_client") // Trying to use this connect string for TimesTen, I am not sure if it is correct.
```

When running my test app, it reports error as below:

> [root@centos-7 ttrest]# ./ttrest 
>   Error running query username="root"
>   SID="localhost:53397/sampledbCS_1122:timesten_client" minSessions=1
>   maxSessions=1000 poolIncrement=1 extAuth=0 : ORA-29158: Unable to open
>   library.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to access Go from Oracle TimesTen In-memory Database is to use the [ODPI-C](https://oracle.github.io/odpi/) based go-goracle SQL driver.

You should use tnsnames.ora to specify a TimesTen service name that will be used to connect to Go. The way you use go-goracle is the same whether you use TimesTen or the Oracle RDBMS.

Answer (score -1):

You can run bin/ttenv.sh to set environment variable, but i can connect from window but i am not yet connect from linux

Comment: Is this an answer or another question?